# who to bulk export mailboxes and save pst as first.lastname

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Trying to write a `powershell` command to export all mailboxes and save them as `firstname.lastname.pst`.
I am new to `powershell` and need some help to get this figured out. Here is an example but `first.lastname` doesn't work because I am sure I am missing stuff.

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Foreach ($mailbox in $mailboxes) {

New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $mailbox -FilePath \\server\share\$_.firstname.$_.LastName.pst }
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work because I am sure I am missing stuff" mean?  Does `-FilePath "\\server\share\$($_.firstname).$($_.LastName).pst` work?

Comment: I was a little of on a syntax, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted FirstName.LastName because it will be easier to bulk import pst files to different server that uses this kind of naming format. Thanks to Bacon Bits for corrections.

get-recipient -identity * | select firstname, lastname, samaccountname | foreach {new-mailboxexportrequest -mailbox $*.SamAccountName -filepath \server\share$($*.firstname).$($_.lastname).pst | export-csv \server\share\list.csv